# Trouble appendingStrings (NSString) within a method?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, uilabel

when i am using string concatenation in method(like -(IBAction)buttonDigitPressed:(id)sender) it shows the blank.I am recall the method automatically terminate the app. what is the problem plz replay me.

`NSString *str= @"";`

```
-(IBAction)buttonDigitPressed:(id)sender{

    int a = (int)[sender tag];
    str= [str stringByAppendingFormat:@"%i",a];
    label1.text= str;
}
```

this is the code. check the code send me the replay where i am doing the mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str` in the method is an autoreleased object. Make it a `copy` property and do

```
self.str = [self.str stringByAppendingFormat:@"%i",a];
label1.text = self.str;
```

If `str` is same as `label1.text` then do this directly.

```
label1.text = [label1.text stringByAppendingFormat:@"%i",a];
```